# Monty Hall Problem. If host open door before the player choose a door.

Tags: probability, monty-hall

What happened if in the Monty Hall problem the host open a door with goat (he knows the door without prize) before the player pick a door. There will be 1/2 of probability of success or 2/3 as the original problem?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}$, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 successful outcome over 2 possible equally likely outcomes gives a probability of $\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: You missed the crucial phrase "2 *equally likely* possible outcomes."  Leaving out that phrase can confuse people into thinking that there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance to win the lottery since there are two outcomes: they win or they lose.

Comment: Thanks.  Silly mistake on my part.

Comment: Thanks, but if the player choose a door first,  the host open this door and reveals the goat (he knows the door have no prize). Then, the host give another oportunity with the 2 remaining doors. 1/2 too?

Comment: @CarlosMangel The scenario you've just given is the Monty Hall Problem.  In this case, the probability is not 1/2 because the probability is conditional.  It becomes 2/3 from the new information.  Your original problem is just the same as picking randomly from two doors.

Comment: @math783625 Thanks, to sum up.                                                                               First scenario (host open before player pick a door)  = 1/2                                                                                                                                                                                                               [goat/OPEN]    [car/CLOSED]    [goat/CLOSED]

Comment: Second scenario:  1- Player pick a door, 2- Host reveals the goat in this door (he knows where is the prize), 3 -  Host give another opportunityto pick with the remaining doors, 4 - The new information becomes  the probability in 2/3 as the original problem.     :)

Comment: Actually the probabilities in the second scenario are the same as in the first scenario, because the player picks a door and then the host opens the _same_ door, The original problem can occur only if the host opens a door that the player did not choose.