# Monty Hall Problem. If contestant choose door with goat and host reveal it....

Tags: probability, monty-hall

I need to confirm this scenario.

1 - The contestant picks a door with a goat behind it.

2 - The host opens this door and reveals the goat.

3 - The host gives the contestant the chance to pick a new door from the two remaining ones.

4 - contestant picks a new door.

5 - The classic scenario. Do you change the door or stay in the same door?

The probability is the same as the original problem (2/3)?

Cheers.

Comment: In step 2, why would the host reveal that the contestant had chosen a door with a goat? That's not how the Monty Hall game works.

Comment: @littleO It appears to deliberately be a variant, judging by the penultimate line.

Comment: How is what you described different from the original Monty Hall problem?

Comment: @VictorS. It differs in step 2. In the original, Monty opens a *different* door containing a goat, not the door chosen by the contestant.

Comment: The Spanish word "concursant" would be naturally translated to English "contestant".  It would improve your post to make this edit.

Comment: There is something a little ridiculous here. In step 3, the host reveals that the door you picked had a goat behind it. Therefore, it's obvious that you will choose another door - you already know your first choice was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for edit the post, i'm not english native.

Comment: In the "classic scenario" there must be a door you chose (which is still closed), another door that is still closed, and a third door that the host opened _after_ you chose yours; furthermore, you and the host both know that the host was _required_ to open a door that was different from your chosen door and that did not reveal the car. After step 2 in your story it is impossible to create the classic scenario, so we must try to guess what you mean in step 5. I think you mean that you are allowed to choose in step 4, then allowed to choose again in step 5 with no further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, the host opens the door that the contestant had chosen initially and reveals it to contain a goat ... after which the contestant picks one of the other two doors ... after which the contestant is given a chance to switch?

If so, it's just 50-50: what we know about the two remaining doors is completely symmetrical, and the prize has to be behind one of them.

Comment: Thanks but 
I but the next answer was so confusing for me [link]https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955942/monty-hall-problem-if-host-open-door-before-the-player-choose-a-door/2955947?noredirect=1#comment6103232_2955947

Comment: @CarlosMangel I am sure that the person you were talking to in that conversation did not quite understand what you were asking: they thought you were asking about the original Monty Hall problem, but you weren't. in this problem , it's just 50-50

Comment: @CarlosMangel Please remember that the "original Monty Hall problem" is so famous that if you ask a question with three doors, two goats, and a car, people will think you mean the original problem unless you explain very clearly how your question is different. (And sometimes they will think you mean the original problem even if you explain the difference.)

Comment: Thanks to all. 50% in each door